# java.lang.ClassCast errors.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to convert the `RDD` of map to wrapped `Array`, I am getting error

Schema:

[image]

When I am trying to convert dataframe to pojo, I am getting exception as below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot 
  be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Code:

```
rdd.map(row => {
  var arrm_list: Seq[Row] = rows.getAs[AnyRef]("ArrTeber").asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]]
  //working fine here
  arrm_list.foreach(x => {
    var arrmtrb__list: Seq[Row] = rows.getAs[AnyRef]("ArrTeberPRD").asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]]

    //working fine here
    arrmtrb__list.foreach(pt => {

      var pd__list: Seq[Row] = rows.getAs[AnyRef]("Pduct").asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]] //raising error
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: use Dataset ... Dataframe is already of `Row` type.. why you need conversion... if you need to map itto pojo dataset is beteer idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above exception is simply a class cast exception, Since **struct cannot be cast to Seq of struct** (Refer Schema: -- Pduct: struct (nullable = true) ). Cast Pduct to Row and then extract nested members.

```
df.map(row => {
  var arrm_list: Seq[Row] = row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("ArrTeber")

  arrm_list.foreach(x => {
    var arrmtrb__list: Seq[Row] = x.getAs[Seq[Row]]("ArrTeberPRD")


    arrmtrb__list.foreach(pt => {
      var pd__list: Row = pt.getAs[Row]("Pduct") //Pduct: struct (nullable = true)

    })
  })

})
```